# How to post Stripe payment form in Joomla 3.x component

Tags: php, post, joomla, http-post, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement a Stripe payments button into my custom Joomla 3.x component called `com_swa`. I'm attempting to do this via [Stripe's checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/tutorial). I've been following [this example](https://gist.github.com/bkrausz/a76f9d7a9b446337d470) from the [Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/php) but I'm having trouble doing the POST.

Here is the code I have so far:

**com_swa/views/ticketpurchase/tmpl/default.php:**

```
<form action="<?php echo JUri::root() .'index.php?option=com_swa&task=ticketpurchase.http_post' ?>" method="POST" >
    <script
        src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key="pk_test_eXamPleK3y"
        data-amount="<?php echo $item->price * 100 ?>"
        data-currency="GBP"
        data-label="Buy now!"
        data-name='SWA'
        data-description="Test description"
        data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
        data-locale="auto"
        data-zip-code="true"
        data-email="<?php echo $this->user->email ?>" >
    </script>
</form>
```

**com_swa/controllers/ticketpurchase.php:**

```
private function http_post() {

    JLog::add( "http_post called", JLog::INFO, 'com_swa' );

    $token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];
    $ammount = $_POST['data-amount'];
    $currency = $_POST['data-currency'];

    var_dump("Token: " . $token);

    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
        'email' => $email,
        'source'  => $token
    ));

    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
        'customer' => $customer->id,
        'amount'   => $ammount,
        'currency' => $currency
    ));

    var_dump("Charge: " . $charge);
    JLog::add('Charge: ' . $charge, JLog::INFO, 'com_swa');

}
```

But this just results in a `500 - View not found [name, type, prefix]: home, html, swaView` error. I have checked the log files and there are no logs indicating that the `http_post()` method has been called.

Right now I just want to var_dump or log a few variables but in the future I will want to redirect to a different view based on the contents of $charge.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is there a view class called "swaViewHome"?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I don't have a view called swaViewHome but I've figured out what I was doing wrong. I'll post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got some sleep and came back to this fresh faced and realised a few things I was doing wrong. I'll list them out here incase anyone else stumbles into the same issues.

1. The form in the view didn't have the hidden inputs `option` and `task`.
2. The function I was trying to call in the controller was private when it should of been public.

Here is what my code looks like now:

**com_swa/views/ticketpurchase/tmpl/default.php:**

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_swa&task=ticketpurchase'); ?>" method="POST" >
    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_swa" />
    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="ticketpurchase.http_post" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ticketId" value="<?php echo $item->id ?>">
    <script
        src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key="pk_test_tDaDvORCWuyXb0VRIHtMStDR"
        data-amount="<?php echo $item->price * 100 ?>"
        data-currency="GBP"
        data-label="Buy now!"
        data-name="SWA"
        data-description="<?php echo $item->event_name . ' - ' . $item->ticket_name; ?>"
        data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
        data-locale="auto"
        data-zip-code="true"
        data-email="<?php echo $this->user->email ?>" >
    </script>
</form>
```

**com_swa/controllers/ticketpurchase.php:**

```
public function http_post() {

    JLog::add( "http_post called", JLog::INFO, 'com_swa' );

    $token = $this->input->getString('stripeToken');
    $email = $this->input->getString('stripeEmail');
    $ticketId = $this->input->getString('ticketId');

    $model = $this->getModel('ticketpurchase');
    $tickets = $model->getItems();
    $member = $model->getMember();

    $ticket = null;
    foreach ($tickets as $t) {
        if ($t->id == $ticketId) {
            $ticket = $t;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($ticket != null) {
        try {
            $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
                'description' => $ticket->event_name . ' - ' . $ticket->ticket_name,
                'amount' => $ticket->price * 100,
                'currency' => 'GBP',
                'receipt_email' => $email,
                'source' => $token,
                'metadata' => array(
                    'ticket_id' => $ticket->id,
                    'member_id' => $member->id
                    )
            ));
            var_dump("Charge: " . $charge);
            JLog::add('Charge: ' . $charge, JLog::INFO, 'com_swa');

        } catch (\Stripe\Error\Base $e) {
            var_dump($e);
        }
    } else {
        // can't find ticketId in items.
    }
    die();
}
```